# 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#map").goMap')

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, typeerror

I realized a map with the plugin goMap(). Therefore I wrote this function:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#map").goMap({ ...
```

What can I do to prevent this Type Error: 
`'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#map").goMap')`
at all other sides, which hasn't a map.

Comment: can you explain - why this question is getting -1 I'm new to this and really don't know what to do...

Comment: I believe you have the plugin library missing.

Comment: I know what to do before asking - but I really didn't know how to ask or search for this I want to have... Because everything was right for me only this typeerror on sites which havn't a map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pages you don't want the map, you can check if goMap is defined before using it. Call it only if it's a function:

```
$(function() {
    if (typeof $("#map").goMap == 'function') {
        $("#map").goMap({ ...
```

Is this what you want?